# Security Sandbox Violation - loading filesystem and networking SWF files

Tags: security, flash, sandbox, flash-cs4

I have built my entire website with Flash and embedded several swf objects (slideshows) into it. Everything works fine when I publish it as swf movie, but now that I want to upload my website, an error message occurs saying:

> Error #2044: Unhandled SecurityErrorEvent:. text=Error #2140: Security sandbox violation: file:///mylayout.swf cannot load file:///slideshow_1.swf. Local-with-filesystem and local-with-networking SWF files cannot load each other.

I know that it has something to do with the fact that one of the swf files is local to the filesystem and the other local via networking, but in my publish settings, I told it to access local files only. That didn't help.

I am hosting my website at `www.all-inkl.com`; besides that, I have not uploaded it yet; I'm just testing it offline. I know I should add this code somewhere:

```
<allow-access-from domain="localhost" secure="true"/>`
```

but I'm not sure where to add it. Maybe to my timeline?

Answer (score 0):

The crossdomain.xml file should have your server name specified. For example take a look at http://www.msn.com/crossdomain.xml

You will have to specify the domain names there. Your server should also be having a crossdomain.xml. Add the corresponding server name there. For example if you are using localhost, try adding

```
<allow-access-from domain="localhost" secure="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

check your swf loading paths. try to specify the entire path like "hppt://www.yourdomain.com/yourweb/mylayout.swf" like this for every swf. and set the html code where the swf embed tag for allowScriptAccess :  "always"